# How can I get some characters around another character in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. The standard chunk of Lorem
>   Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.
>   Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by
>   Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form.

I want to search for `1500s` and then select some characters around it, like: `ever since the 1500s, when an unknown`. Considering that I am searching in a for loop, trying to find all the `1500s` in a very long string. So the next loop would be finding: `used since the 1500s is reproduced`

I am using regular expression to find the substring:

```
substring = re.findall('1500s', string)
```

But how to select some 20 characters around it as well?

Comment: Well, `.{20}` is the expression for any 20 characters

Comment: Is it [this](https://regex101.com/r/hI61Tu/2) you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cricket_007 said, you can try using `.{20}` as bookends to your regular expression pattern.

```
substring = re.findall('.{0,20}1500s.{0,20}', s)
```

Comment: This fails when the search string shows up too close to the start or end of the text; I would use `.{0,20}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 r"(.{20})?(1500)(.{20})?" g
```

This will search for **"1500"** at the start/end of the string as well. I put them in groups just to tidy up the regex.

[See it work here](https://regex101.com/r/q83k8C/2)